# Redis messages are consumed by Spring boot application after Redis restart

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

First started Redis Server then started application.As soon as messages appears in the Redis stream those are getting consumed properly. In mean while if restarts the Redis Server as application is already running it is not consuming new messages from the Redis Server.
Could someone please assist on this.
Is there any more configuration needs to be done, to continue to process message after redis server restart.

I'm using StreamMessageListenerContainer with consumergroup.

@Bean
public Subscription listener(RedisStreamConsumer streamListener, RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) throws InterruptedException {

```
     StreamMessageListenerContainer<String, MapRecord<String, Object, String>> listenerContainer =
             StreamMessageListenerContainer.create(redisTemplate().getConnectionFactory(),
            StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamMessageListenerContainerOptions.builder()
                    .hashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer()).hashValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer())
                    .pollTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(100))
                    .build());
    Subscription subscription = listenerContainer.receive(Consumer.from(groupName, consumerName),
            StreamOffset.create(consumerstreamName, ReadOffset.lastConsumed()), streamListener);
    subscription.await(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
    listenerContainer.start();
    return subscription;
}
```

Comment: Hi did you got solution for this?